# Speed up sub-array shuffling and storing

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, shuffle

I have a list of integers (`di`), and another list (`rang_indx`) made up of `numpy` sub-arrays of integers (code below). For each of these sub-arrays, I need to store in a separate list (`indx`) a number of random elements, given by the `di` list.

For what I can see [`np.random.shuffle()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) will not shuffle the elements within the sub-arrays but the *sub-arrays themselves* within `rang_indx`, which is not what I need. Hence, I need to use a `for` loop to first shuffle the sub-arrays (in place), and then another one (combined with a `zip()`) to generate the `indx` list.

This function is called millions of times as part of a larger code. Is there a way I can speed up the process?

```
import numpy as np


def func(di, rang_indx):
    # Shuffle each sub-array in place.
    for _ in rang_indx:
        np.random.shuffle(_)

    # For each shuffled sub-array, only keep as many elements as those
    # indicated by the 'di' array.
    indx = [_[:i] for (_, i) in zip(*[rang_indx, di.astype(int)])]

    return indx


# This data is not fixed, and will change with each call to func()
di = np.array([ 4.,  2.,   0.,   600.,  12.,  22.,  13.,  21.,  25.,  25.,  12.,  11.,
         7.,  12.,  10.,  13.,   5.,  10.])
rang_indx = [np.array([]), np.array([189, 195, 209, 214, 236, 237, 255, 286, 290, 296, 301, 304, 321,
       323, 327, 329]), np.array([164, 171, 207, 217, 225, 240, 250, 263, 272, 279, 284, 285, 289]), np.array([101, 162, 168, 177, 179, 185, 258, 261, 264, 269, 270, 278, 281,
       287, 293, 298]), np.array([111, 127, 143, 156, 159, 161, 181, 182, 183, 194, 196, 198, 204,
       205, 210, 212, 235, 239, 267, 268, 297]), np.array([107, 116, 120, 128, 130, 136, 137, 144, 152, 155, 157, 166, 169,
       170, 184, 186, 192, 218, 220, 226, 228, 241, 245, 246, 247, 251,
       252, 253]), np.array([ 99, 114, 118, 121, 131, 134, 158, 216, 219, 221, 224, 231, 233,
       234, 243, 244]), np.array([ 34,  37,  38,  48,  56,  78,  84, 100, 108, 117, 122, 123, 132,
       149, 151, 153, 163, 178, 180, 191, 199, 202, 208, 211]), np.array([ 31,  40,  41,  45,  51,  53,  57,  60,  61,  66,  67,  69,  71,
        75,  85,  90,  95,  96, 167, 173, 174, 176, 188, 190, 197, 206]), np.array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   6,  11,  12,  13,  17,  25,  33,  36,  47,
        58,  64,  76,  87,  94, 160, 165, 172, 175, 187, 193, 201, 203]), np.array([  4,  16,  18,  19, 109, 113, 115, 124, 138, 142, 145, 150]), np.array([103, 105, 106, 112, 125, 135, 139, 140, 141, 146, 147, 154]), np.array([102, 104, 110, 119, 126, 129, 133, 148]), np.array([29, 32, 42, 43, 55, 63, 72, 77, 79, 83, 91, 92]), np.array([35, 49, 59, 73, 74, 81, 86, 88, 89, 97, 98]), np.array([30, 39, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 62, 65, 68, 80, 82, 93]), np.array([ 8, 10, 15, 27, 70]), np.array([ 5,  7,  9, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 28])]

func(di, rang_indx)
```

Comment: `rang_indx[0]` has 0 elements, but `di[0]` is `4`. Are you trying to draw 4 elements from a population of 0?

Comment: Yes. In such cases, the result should be an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one idea with the intention to keep minimal work when we loop and use one loop only -

1. Create a `2D` random array in interval `[0,1)` to cover the max. length of subarrays.
2. For each subarray, set the invalid places to `1.0`. Get argsort for each row. Those 1s corresponding to the invalid places would stay at the back because there were no 1s in the original random array. Thus, we have the indices array.
3. Slice each row of those indices array to the extent of the lengths listed in `di`.
4. Start a loop and slice each subarray from `rang_indx` using those sliced indices.

Hence, the implementation -

```
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in rang_indx])
di0 = np.minimum(lens, di.astype(int))
invalid_mask = lens[:,None] <= np.arange(lens.max())
rand_nums = np.random.rand(len(lens), lens.max())
rand_nums[invalid_mask] = 1
shuffled_indx = np.argpartition(rand_nums, lens-1, axis=1)

out = []
for i,all_idx in enumerate(shuffled_indx):
    if lens[i]==0:
        out.append(np.array([]))
    else:
        slice_idx = all_idx[:di0[i]]
        out.append(rang_indx[i][slice_idx])
```

**Approach #2 :** Another way with doing much of the setup work in an efficient manner within the loop -

```
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in rang_indx])
di0 = np.minimum(lens, di.astype(int))
out = []
for i in range(len(lens)):
    if lens[i]==0:
        out.append(np.array([]))
    else:
        k = di0[i]
        slice_idx = np.argpartition(np.random.rand(lens[i]), k-1)[:k]
        out.append(rang_indx[i][slice_idx])
```

Comment: This crashes with an `IndexError: index 19 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0` at the line `out.append(rang_indx[i][slice_idx])`.

Comment: @Gabriel Check out the edits please. Didn't cover a corner case earlier.

Comment: Thank you Divakar! Although it looks more complicated, it is almost 2X faster than my code.

Comment: @Gabriel Haha to be honest I was not expecting this to be faster, given the setup overhead. But I guess with a lot of iterations that pays off. I was just trying out my vectorization skills :)

Comment: That's what I thought too when I saw all the setup needed, and that two `for` loops and an `if` block were being used. Vectorization always pays off apparently.

Comment: @Gabriel Check out the just added `Approach #2 ` too.

Comment: Although the 2nd approach looks a lot cleaner it is only ~20% faster than my original code, while the 1st approach is ~50% faster.

Comment: @Gabriel I see. Thanks for getting back with the numbers!