# Shuffle multidimensional array by columns and update list of indexes accordingly

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, random

Given an `N` rows by `M` columns array, I need to shuffle it by *columns* and at the same time update a separate list of (unique) column indexes to point to the new positions of the shuffled elements.

For example, take the following `(3, 5)` array

```
a = [[ 0.15337424  0.21176979  0.19846229  0.5245618   0.24452392]
     [ 0.17460481  0.45727362  0.26914808  0.81620202  0.8898504 ]
     [ 0.50104826  0.22457154  0.24044079  0.09524352  0.95904348]]
```

and the list of column indexes:

```
idxs = [0 3 4]
```

If I shuffle the array by columns so it looks like this:

```
a = [[ 0.24452392  0.19846229  0.5245618   0.21176979  0.15337424]
     [ 0.8898504   0.26914808  0.81620202  0.45727362  0.17460481]
     [ 0.95904348  0.24044079  0.09524352  0.22457154  0.50104826]]
```

the indexes array should be modified to look like this:

```
idxs = [4 2 0]
```

I can shuffle the array by columns by transposing it before and after the shuffle (see code below), but I'm not sure how I could update the indexes list. This whole process needs to be as fast as possible, since it will be performed millions of times with new arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def getData():
    # Array of (N, M) dimensions
    N, M = 10, 500
    a = np.random.random((N, M))

    # List of unique column indexes in a.
    # This list could be empty, or it could have a length of 'M'
    # (ie: contain all the indexes in the range of 'a').
    P = int(M * np.random.uniform())
    idxs = np.arange(0, M)
    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
    idxs = idxs[:P]

    return a, idxs


a, idxs = getData()

# Shuffle a by columns
b = a.T
np.random.shuffle(b)
a = b.T

# Update the 'idxs' list?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the random permutations for the column indices with `np.random.permutation` -

```
col_idx = np.random.permutation(a.shape[1])
```

Get shuffled input array -

```
shuffled_a = a[:,col_idx]
```

Then, simply index into the sorted indices for `col_idx` with `idxs` for the traced back version -

```
shuffled_idxs = col_idx.argsort()[idxs]
```

Sample run -

```
In [236]: a # input array
Out[236]: 
array([[ 0.1534,  0.2118,  0.1985,  0.5246,  0.2445],
       [ 0.1746,  0.4573,  0.2691,  0.8162,  0.8899],
       [ 0.501 ,  0.2246,  0.2404,  0.0952,  0.959 ]])

In [237]: col_idx = np.random.permutation(a.shape[1])

# Let's use the sample permuted column indices to verify desired o/p
In [238]: col_idx = np.array([4,2,3,1,0])

In [239]: shuffled_a = a[:,col_idx]

In [240]: shuffled_a
Out[240]: 
array([[ 0.2445,  0.1985,  0.5246,  0.2118,  0.1534],
       [ 0.8899,  0.2691,  0.8162,  0.4573,  0.1746],
       [ 0.959 ,  0.2404,  0.0952,  0.2246,  0.501 ]])

In [241]: col_idx.argsort()[idxs]
Out[241]: array([4, 2, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks you Divakar! I'm trying to improve the performance of a function (as you might have guessed from my previous questions), and the answer you gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079837/1391441 is still producing the fastest results.

Answer (score 0):

```
original_index = range(a.shape[1])
permutation_series = pd.Series(original_index)
permutation_series.index = np.random.permutation(original_index)
new_idx = permutation_series[old_idx]
a = a[:,permutation_series.index]
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does differently from OP's and how that solves the problem/answers their question. I recommend this guide on creating a useful answer stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

data array must be shuffle using index array, so first shuffle the index array and use that to shuffle the data array.

```
import numpy as np

def getData():
    # Array of (N, M) dimensions
    a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
    # [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
    # [ 5  6  7  8  9]
    # [10 11 12 13 14]]
    idxs = np.arange(a.shape[0]) #  [0 1 2]
    return a, idxs

a, idxs = getData()

# Shuffle a by columns
b = a.T
# [[ 0  5 10]
# [ 1  6 11]
# [ 2  7 12]
# [ 3  8 13]
# [ 4  9 14]]

np.random.shuffle(idxs)  #  [2 0 1]
a = b[:, idxs]

# [[10  0  5]
# [11  1  6]
# [12  2  7]
# [13  3  8]
# [14  4  9]]
```

so idxs will be useful if you want to shuffle any other array say x to match shuffling of array a